# Creating MvvmCross PCL to target Wp7.1 Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, .Net 4.5 and SL4 and higher

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

After researching MVVMCross project, I am very keen to use it in a new mobile project and began setting out my project today. All was going fine until I tried to target the exact frameworks Stuart does in the "N=0 : A first MvvmCross Application" youtube video. I've no idea why this collection isn't allowed and I'm not as knowledgeable on PCLs and "profiles" as I could be.

Environment:
I'm using VS2012, although VS2013 is installed also. WP7.1 is installed as is SL5 and Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. I've tried to repair both Xamarin installations because I thought the issue might have been that I installed WP7.1 after the Xamarin pair.

Also worth noting is that if I uncheck Windows Phone 7.5 and higher then it still won't work. I have to also set Silverlight 5 for the dialog to let me proceed. I'm not sure what more I can do do get this working so I'd appreciate any help I can get. All I want is to basically target the exact frameworks as are in that video mentioned above.

Comment: Might have just solved this issue by following the directions at [PCL Setup](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Monotouch or Monodroid projects right now in Xamarin, so that link will not realy help you. They are called now Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. So what I've done that helped me, I've extended Profile 7, so it now supports WP7, iOS, Android and WinStore and it works great, no problems yet and I've already complete a couple of projects with it. So at that link - [PCL Setup](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html) -  you can find where all the profiles located and with that info try to extend Profile 7 as I suggested. So I've coppied the `Windows Phone 7.xml` from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile131\SupportedFrameworks` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7\SupportedFrameworks`

Comment: Just to clarify my comment above about the PCL Setup link: I copied the Xamarin.Android.xml and Xamarin.iOS.xml files from Profile24 to Profile104 and that made it work. Would that be correct? I've no idea what these profiles are all about so I can't ascertain whether your instructions would help me or not. It's working now with Profile 104 after I copied those two Xamarin files into the "Supported Frameworks"

Comment: Yes, at all the main point is to extend the existing profile and it doesn't mean to extend only Profile7, you can extend any other, you just should make sure that it works after extending. But Profile104 doesn't have a lot of libraries that has Profile7 like System.Net.Http or System.Link, System.IO and a lot of others. So you will be a little bit restricted with it

Comment: So I should use Profile7? Will that support all the platforms I want to target? How do I make sure it works after extending? Apologies but I know nothing about these profiles, having been a WPF and Silverlight developer for years I've never come across this .NET Portable folder and all its profiles beneath. ELI5 if you could :) Thanks Choper.

Comment: You should extend Profile7 with the plartforms that you need after that you will be able to target the platforms you want to work with in the PCL

Comment: Just after checking my folder to see if I can follow your directions and I don't even have a Profile 7. It jumps from Profile 6 - Profile 14. Are there any good resources out there you'd recommend I read to get up to speed with these profiles and how they are extended and what it even means to "extend" them. I'm a bit lost tbh.

Comment: I've provided the link to that folder in my answer

Comment: Under extending I mean to add the xml config files for the platforms that you need. So for example profile 7 already support WinStore, iOS, Android and .Net4.5, so you should extend it with WP7

Comment: Ok, got it there now. Didn't notice the v4.0 and v4.5 in the folder path there initially. So now that I've done that I can change to Profile7 in the .csproj? Thanks Choper.

Comment: I'd mark this question as answered but it won't allow me since I've not got enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

The video and PCL setup link are out of date now that Xamarin has released official support for PCLs.  I'd recommend targeting the following platforms:

- Windows Phone 8
- Windows Store apps (Windows 8)
- .NET Framework 4.5
- Xamarin.iOS
- Xamarin.Android

And, optionally you can target Silverlight 5.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that's just the platforms I'm now targetting! :)